# How to retain state of div (hide/show) after clicking back and returning to form page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a form that has several hidden divs that are set to show/hide when a radio button is clicked, a checkbox is checked, or in this case, an option is selected from a drop-down box.

At this point, when a form is submitted it gets passed to the server and returns an HTML page with a list of required fields that are missing information. From there you can click back and return to the page to enter the required fields and submit the form again. I have no control over this process or the server.

However, when the user clicks back or the return button on the required fields page on browsers such as Chrome, IE, Safari, any divs that should remain displayed are hidden again. I've mitigated this issue with certain functions by using onLoad but the issue still persists when it comes to selecting an option from a drop-down box.

**Question:** How do I retain the div made visible when an option is selected upon returning to the page/form on all browsers (Chrome, IE, Safari, etc.)?

**Note:** For this purpose, I would like to avoid using local storage, if possible. Also, I have tried looking for examples on here but the solutions available don't seem to work as expected, although I may be to blame for that due to the lack of experience working with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div1').hide();
  $("#location").change(function() {
    var selected_option = $('#location').val();
    if (selected_option === 'other') {
      $('#div1').show();
    } else {
      $('#div1').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="test.cgi" id="form" name="myform">
  <label for="location" class="label-med">Location:</label>
  <SELECT id="location" class="input">
    <optgroup label="Locations">
      <OPTION SELECTED VALUE="">(Select One)</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="1">1</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="2">2</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="3">3</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="4">4</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="5t">5</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="6">6</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="7">7</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="8">8</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="9">9</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="10">10</OPTION>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
  </SELECT>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <label class="label-med" for="location">Location:</label>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" name="other_cunyloc" id="location" MAXLENGTH="80" SIZE="25" class="input"></INPUT>
  </div>
  <INPUT class="button" TYPE="SUBMIT" Value="Submit">
  </INPUT>
</FORM>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/artboycat/m9m4nL1z/18/).

Comment: "I would like to avoid using local storage" what about cookies. session variables. These are all viable options for persisting some data from one page to another. Otherwise you could use AJAX

Comment: The only ways to maintain state across page loads are local storage (localStorage/cookies), server storage, or URL parameters.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms, if it's a last resort I'm open to anything as long as it can be done with js. However, I was trying to do something with local storage but I couldn't get it to work as intended.

Comment: Well. If you don’t want to make it complicated, you should just use some form of local storage whether it be cookies, session variables or local storage itself. Ajax would be useful if you needed to send these values to the server but it’s just unnecessary to do that if there’s no need. Why don’t you post what you’ve tried to do with local storage so far and I’ll have a look.